# How to install Samsung AllShare or recommendations for other DNLA Server options?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, wine

How can I install **Samsung Allshare** ( a windows app) on ubuntu 11.04?

I have tried unsuccessfully using Wine.

Alternatively, can you recommend other DNLA server options?

Comment: Why cant you do it via wine - what is the installation issue that you are battling with?  The requirement says you need .net3.5 - so have you installed .net3.5 via winetricks?  Please edit your question with any responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot install `AllShare` on linux without wine but I would not recommend that at all.

Why don't you try using a better `DLNA` server like [Serviio](http://www.serviio.org)?

It's free, works great with my Samsung TV, has more file format support then `AllShare` and does the job on the background not bothering you.

I mentioned Serviio but there are a bunch of free DLNA servers out there. Do a Google search on DLNA servers and choose one. Start with `Serviio` tough, it's recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I`ve downloaded Serviio. Since I`m newbee on Ubuntu, please, help me how to install it on my pc?

Comment: You need to have java installed and ffmpeg (look in software center). After that there is no need to install, you can just extract the files that are in the tar.gz and read the readme file to start the server ;) If you need further assist let me know and I'll guide you slowly.

Comment: Here is a link to the instructions: http://www.serviio.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5